# How to differentiate command from the output using color

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have to differentiate command from the output using color

like this

```
$ cat file-name (this should be in some color say like red)
some test in file OUTPUT (this output should be in some other color say like green)
```

so that I can easy differentiate command from its output in case of commands with large output

And i have to make it it work for every command that is typed on terminal
if possible even command not found can be printed out in different color

Comment: You can refer to this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146145/how-do-i-stop-a-bash-shell-ps1-color-to-stop-at-the-end-of-the-command

Comment: How nice! A question about Debian, with an answer on [unix.se].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add this to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
        RED="\[\033[0;31m\]"
     YELLOW="\[\033[1;33m\]"
      GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
       BLUE="\[\033[1;34m\]"
  LIGHT_RED="\[\033[1;31m\]"
LIGHT_GREEN="\[\033[1;32m\]"
       CYAN="\[\033[0;36m\]"
 LIGHT_CYAN="\[\033[1;36m\]"
      WHITE="\[\033[1;37m\]"
 LIGHT_GRAY="\[\033[0;37m\]"
 COLOR_NONE="\[\e[0m\]"

PS1="$PS1${LIGHT_RED}"
trap '[[ -t 1 ]] && tput sgr0' DEBUG
```

The colour code variables aren't necessary, but they simplify things. Change the `LIGHT_RED` to other colours to suit your need. Effect:

[image: RED]
[image: BLUE]

You'll have to source the `.bashrc` for changes to take effect:

```
. .bashrc
```

<sup><sub>The `LIGHT_RED` isn't really light red for me because of the colour profile I have set for the terminal.</sub></sup>

Sources:

1. [How do I stop a bash shell PS1 color to stop at the end of the command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146148/70524)
2. [Bash command prompt with virtualenv and git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23399183/bash-command-prompt-with-virtualenv-and-git-branch) (for the colours)

Comment: yes this one works the way i wanted it

Comment: but with this i am able to color the command but i am unable color the output of the command i used this for that `trap '[[ -t 1 ]] && tput setaf 2' DEBUG`

Comment: @user310685 I'd usually use the terminal's colour settings to set the colour of the output.

Comment: yes that works good

Comment: `trap '[[ -t 1 ]] && tput sgr0' DEBUG` could you explain what do this mean?

Comment: @Luke the `DEBUG` trap runs on each command, just before execution. `[[ -t 1 ]]` tests for a TTY on stdout, and `tput sgr0` resets the colour. Essentially, it resets the colour each time a command is executed (otherwise the command output would be coloured the same way as well)

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
grep --color=always . file-name
```

The dot is essential in this case, it's the regular expression for matching any single character.

Comment: how shall i try this

Comment: but i guess this wont work for other commands like (ls)

Comment: @user310685 use this command in your putty, and yes this is for replacing 'cat' it won't work with ls.

Comment: i wanted to make it work for each and every command

Answer (score 0):

You can use ANSI escape sequence to differentiate the command from its output, like this:

```
echo -e "\e[31m"; echo "ls -al"; echo -e "\e[0m"; echo -e "\e[32m"; ls -al --color=never ; echo -e "\e[0m";
```

[image]

Source: http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting

Comment: this does not work

Comment: i guess there is some difference in version that y it dose not work for me , but i guess making it work will not make it work for every command. i have to manually add it into every command